# Increase the width of the style

Tags: html, css

I currently have something like this::

```
<html>
    <head>
    <style>
       UseA
           {
            border-radius: 10px;
            background: #BADA55;
            height:500px;
            width:500px;
           }
    </style>
    </head>
  <body>    
          
        <UseA>
                Hello , My name is Jim Some thing to test
        </UseA>
    
  </body>
 </html>
```

my output is something like this

[image]

How can I increase the width and the length of the styled tag so it looks like my requirement below

Comment: Don't make up your own elements. `<UseA>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your non-standard element is apparently inline by default.

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/52RCt/

```
UseA {
    display: inline-block; /* or 'block', depending on your needs */
}
```

You'd probably be better off using standard HTML, though:

```
<div class="UseA">...</div>
```

In the latter case no additional CSS is necessary, as a div is a block-level element by default.

Comment: Thanks that helped. Marked as answer after timer

Answer (score 1):

add display block to your css

```
  UseA {
      border-radius: 10px;
      background: #BADA55;
      height:500px;
      width:500px;
      display:block;
  }
```

check this fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/victorrseloy/9gwNX/

Comment: Thanks for the suggetsion

Answer (score 0):

This "UseA", as any other nondefined HTML-Tags, have a default "display: inline". Width and height is always automatic for inline Tags.

You should give it "display: block" or "display: inline-block". So:

```
   UseA
       {
        display: block;
        border-radius: 10px;
        background: #BADA55;
        height:500px;
        width:500px;
       }
```

P.s. IMHO you should learn a litte bit about "fluid design" about google.

Answer (score 0):

The best you can do is change your made up UseA element into a div. Adding *inline-block* is not necessary due to standard settings for the div element.

```
<html>
    <head>
    <style>
       div#useA
           {
            border-radius: 10px;
            background: #BADA55;
            height:500px;
            width:500px;
           }
    </style>
    </head>
  <body>    

        <div id="useA">
                Hello , My name is Jim Some thing to test
        </div>

  </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a padding on your class like this. Also, don't use non-standard html element. **[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/QmmWk/3/)**

```
.UseA {
border-radius: 10px;
background: #BADA55;
padding:30px;
}
```

your html

```
 <div class="UseA">Hello , My name is Jim Some thing to test</div>
```